# circular logging in python

Tags: python, logging

I am currently using `logging` package in Python to log statements to a single file (`log.log`)

The problem I am facing is if the log file gets too large, it takes a lot of time to open the log file.

I thought after a pre-defined file size or line numbers, I can create a log file called `log.log.1`, and continue running with a fresh `log.log`.

Also, after `log.log.5`, the old logs should get deleted automatically.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The `logging` package handles this directly, see [*Using file rotation*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-file-rotation) in the Logging Cookbook documentation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The question isn't whether there's a tool or library; it's about whether a Python 'package' exists. In other languages, e.g. Java, a 'package' is reasonably equivalent to a 'module' in Python, and it's generally synonymous enough for a Google search for 'Python package' to yield the Python page about modules.

Comment: @MichaelScheper: this user clearly meant to ask for a recommended project. The question doesn't need it and I've edited it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how you want to rotate the logs, you can use either the [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) to rotate files at a given time interval (for example, create a new file ever day, or every hour); or you can use the [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) to create new files after they reach a certain size.

The [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook) has examples to help you get started.